# What is the easiest way to 'Goose' in Titanfall

Tags: achievements, titanfall

In Titanfall there is a challenge and an achievement:

> **Gooser** Shoot X pilots while they are ejecting

Ejecting pilots are very quick, often cloaked, at medium to long range and always at full health (taking multiple shots with most weapons).

For some players this is easy, twitch reflexes or pure skill make it easy, but many players find it extremely hard - getting even one 'Goose' is a huge challenge.

Is there any tactic, weapon or strategy that can make this easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally did this with Arc Cannon + Capacitor:

This is the most reliable method of getting Gooser kills that I've found:

1. Equip the Arc Cannon + Capacitor
2. Stand just out of nuclear ejection range
3. Start charging as the doomed titan starts it's ejection animation - if you land the dooming hit the next charged hit will be at the top of the pilots ejection parabola.
4. Look up before they eject
5. Don't aim with the LT, you'll hit the pilot if they're near your white targeting reticle.
6. Note how sloppy my aim is - I still get the kill because of the wide area that the fully charged Arc hits.

Doing it this way I got all the Gen 5 Gooser kills within about 10 rounds of Last Titan Standing.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to be in a titan - titan weapons kill pilots fast.

That is, if you can hit them mid-air. Personally I find the Arc Cannon (without capacitor) the best, but some players prefer the Chaingun.

Alternatively you can rodeo a titan - when the pilot ejects you will eject with him. If you got for this method, you'll probably want the Smart Pistol, RC-101 or an SMG to win the duel.

Answer (score 1):

I am an old guy and could not to date master the gooser challenge. I have completed the challenge and then some but never shot a single pilot.  I can effectively beat down a titan and get an airborne kill when the pilot ejects. If he does not eject then it becomes an execution.  I can now get 2 goosers out of 3 titan beat downs. Works for an old guy like me that cannot track air borne pilots with a weapon. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I use the krabar often because when they eject, you can track them and with the right timing you can get the kill. Tip: Aim below the pilot but not too far, then pull the trigger. If you are not good with a sniper, use a smart pistol. Good luck and happy hunting.